# How to make a paragraph not clip through anything or go offscreen

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to not let a paragraph clip through an image and also how to not let the text in the paragraph go offscreen I am using

to make the paragraph I typed in a paragraph(Apar) and it made the text go off screen and I typed in the other one the other paragraph(Cpar) and it clipped into the image please help me fix this. Thank you

```css
     body {
     margin: 0;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     min-height: 100vh;
     }
  
     header {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
     }
  
     .nav {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     display: flex;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     }
  
     .nav li {
     margin: 0 0 0 2em;
     }
   
     main {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     padding: 2%;
     background-color: white;
     }
  
     footer {
     flex: 0 0 auto;
     padding: 2%;
     background-color: white;
     }
    .BigData {
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 900px;
     padding-top: 40px;
    
     }
      .Apar {
      text-align: right;
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      left: 1450px;
      color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      }
      .Cpar {
      color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: right;
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      }
```

```html
    <head>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <meta charset = "UTF=8">
        <meta name="description" content="denvware software solutions">
        <title>Denvware</title>
     </head>
    <body style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)">
        <header>   
                <img src="Logo1denv.png" width="160" style="background- 
     color:antiquewhite" class="ImageLogo"/>
           
                        <ul class="nav">
                                <li><h3>Home</h3></li>
                                <li><h3>About</h3></li>
                                <li><h3>Contact</h3></li>
                        </ul>
        </header>
            <main style="background-color: rgb(53, 60, 68)">
                    <img src="Bigdata3.jpg" width="720" class="BigData"/>
                    <p class="Apar">Insert Text Here</p>
                    <p class="Cpar">Insert Text Here</p>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <h6>Copyright</h6>
            </footer>
     </body>
    
     </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Omar. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish here, but the main reason your text is behaving like that is because of the `position: absolute` you have set in your paragraphs.

Positioned elements leave the [normal flow](https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101/), and become relative to the first positioned parent they have or, as it is in your case, the "body" element. So your `Apar`
will always be at 200px from the top of the page, regardless of any image it might find.

Comment: Yes I changed the position to fixed and it fixed the Apar bu the Cpar would clip through the image